# how to get attr id without # sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, attr

this things make me confuse
I'm try to get anchor attribute and replace it to input id with this way, but things doesnt work if anchor have longer id. How I can get id without sign#

```js
$('.srcFilter a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = $(this).attr('href');
  var b = a.slice(1,6);
  $('input').attr( 'id',b);
 })
```

```css
a{
margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="srcAll" />
<div class="srcFilter">
<a href="#item1">all</a>
<a href="#item2">item</a>
<a href="#item3">code</a>
<a href="#itemlong">item long</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `a.(1,6)` supposed to be? Is that a typo for `a.substr(1, 6)`?

Comment: `var a = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');` Why not just replace it

Comment: You can use `.substr(1)` to get everything after the first character. When you leave out the length, it means to go to the end of the string.

Comment: I use a.slice(1,6), I thought its work fine, but substr its more better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(e){
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var h = e.href;
    h = h.split("#")[1]; 

    // alternatives
    // h = h.substr(1, h.length);  -- might not fit every situation
    // h = h.match('#(.*)');
    let inp = e.parentNode.previousElementSibling;
    inp.setAttribute('id', h);
    inp.value = "May id is: "+h; //debugging -))
});  
})
```

```html
<input id="srcAll" />
<div class="srcFilter">
<a href="#item1">all</a>
<a href="#item2">item</a>
<a href="#item3">code</a>
<a href="#itemlong">item long</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I didnt notice if there alternative to get this way, so split its work to rather than use slice and it's work really good. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
var b = a.substr(1);
```

When you leave out the `length` argument to `substr()`, it defaults to the rest of the string.

Comment: I thought it would be using slice, its better use substr, thanks for advice I should be notice myself in future

Answer (score 2):

Use `.substr(1)` to get anchor attribute without 0-index '#' and add jquery. Check the result:

```js
$('.srcFilter a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = $(this).attr('href');
  var b = a.substr(1);
  $('input').attr('id',b);
        console.log(b);
 });
```

```css
a{
margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="srcAll" />
<div class="srcFilter">
<a href="#item1">all</a>
<a href="#item2">item</a>
<a href="#item3">code</a>
<a href="#itemlong">item long</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```
$('.srcFilter a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var a = $(this).attr('href');
        var b = a.substring(1); // var b = a.substr(1);
        $('input#srcAll').attr('id',b);
});
```

Give it a try, it will work.